# Border on canvas circle not being removed with context.lineWidth = 0;

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Learning Javascript, I tried to draw a clock, but when it starts to draw the hands, the outline of the clock gets a border.

If I remove the section of Javascript under `/* Draw the Hour Hand */` the border goes as well as the hand.

I would have thought `context.lineWidth = 0;` on line 9 of the JavaScript would have stopped the clock border, but it doesn't.

How do I stop producing the border around the edge of the clock?

```js
/* Define variables for clock canvas */
var canvas = document.getElementById("clock");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var clockRadius = canvas.width / 2;

/* Draw filled clock outline */
context.beginPath();
context.arc(clockRadius, clockRadius, clockRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.lineWidth = 0;
context.fillStyle = "#bf7b28";
context.fill();

/* Add the numbers */
context.font = clockRadius / 10 + "px arial";
context.fillStyle = "black";
context.textAlign = "center"; /* centre horizontally */
context.textBaseline = "middle"; /* centre virtically */
/* keep looping until i <= 12, add 1 each loop */
for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
  context.fillText(i, clockRadius + clockRadius * 0.9 * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / 12), clockRadius - (clockRadius * 0.9 * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / 12)));
}

/* Get the current time */
var date = new Date();
var mins = date.getMinutes();
var secs = date.getSeconds();
var hours = date.getHours();

/* hours % 12 = 24 hour to 12 hour (get remainder after hours is div by 12) */
var fullHours = hours % 12 + mins / 60 + secs / 3600;
var hourAngle = fullHours * 2 * Math.PI / 12
var minsAngle = mins * 2 * Math.PI / 60
var secsAngle = secs * 2 * Math.PI / 60

/* Draw the Hour Hand */
context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.moveTo(clockRadius, clockRadius);
context.lineTo(clockRadius + clockRadius * 0.5 * Math.sin(hourAngle), clockRadius - (clockRadius * 0.5 * Math.cos(hourAngle)));
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.stroke();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-GB">

<head>
  <title>Javascript Clock</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

  <canvas id="clock" width="500px" height="500px">
          <p>Please update your browser</p>     <!-- Fallback used to display message on older browsers which do not support <canvas> tag -->
    </canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `beginPath()` before drawing the clock hand so your arc is not affected by the `stroke` call of the hand.

```
/* Define variables for clock canvas */
var canvas = document.getElementById("clock");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var clockRadius = canvas.width / 2;

/* Draw filled clock outline */
context.beginPath()
context.arc(clockRadius, clockRadius, clockRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.lineWidth = 0;
context.fillStyle = "#bf7b28";
context.fill();

/* Add the numbers */
context.font = clockRadius / 10 + "px arial";
context.fillStyle = "black";
context.textAlign = "center"; /* centre horizontally */
context.textBaseline = "middle"; /* centre virtically */
/* keep looping until i <= 12, add 1 each loop */
for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
  context.fillText(i, clockRadius + clockRadius * 0.9 * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / 12), clockRadius - (clockRadius * 0.9 * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / 12)));
}

/* Get the current time */
var date = new Date();
var mins = date.getMinutes();
var secs = date.getSeconds();
var hours = date.getHours();

/* hours % 12 = 24 hour to 12 hour (get remainder after hours is div by 12) */
var fullHours = hours % 12 + mins / 60 + secs / 3600;
var hourAngle = fullHours * 2 * Math.PI / 12
var minsAngle = mins * 2 * Math.PI / 60
var secsAngle = secs * 2 * Math.PI / 60

/* Draw the Hour Hand */

context.beginPath(); // Here, begin a new path so the arc is not affected by the stroke call

context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.moveTo(clockRadius, clockRadius);
context.lineTo(clockRadius + clockRadius * 0.5 * Math.sin(hourAngle), clockRadius - (clockRadius * 0.5 * Math.cos(hourAngle)));
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.stroke();
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to do this for each hand or just for the first hand?

Comment: No problem ! It depends if you want to apply different styles to your hand. In your case one beginPath should be enough. try it and then adjust accordingly. Please mark my answer as solution if it works for you

Comment: It is late here so I will try your suggestion in the morning. If it works, I will mark it as a solution.